# Notation: Unknown integral range for general case

Tags: integration, notation

If I don't know the range of values to integrate over, but want to provide a general notation to integrate over all $c$, how would I write this notation?

Would this work?

$$
\int_{c} f(c)dc
$$

Comment: Presumably, this is what you want: let $X$ be the set of all those $c$ over which you want to integrate. Then the integral can be expressed as $\int_X f(c) dc$. Your notation does not make sense because the variable of integration cannot appear in the limits of integration.

Comment: What do you call "all $c$" ??? This is pretty undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to put under your integral sign is the domain in which the variable $c$ belongs. For instance, if $f$ is defined on all the real numbers, you would write 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(c) dc$$

(note that it doesn't imply that your integral has a sense ; it can be divergent).

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.